# Why are the fees hard coded?

Tags: transaction-fees

Most cryptocurrencies let you choose your fee. Why does Monero use a hard coded fee?

Edit: Or rather I should say why is the minimum fee hard coded.

Comment: @seekadventure I'm looking for the rationale behind this aspect of Monero.

Comment: fair enough. I can see the distinction and retract my claim that is looked like a duplicate

Comment: @seekadventure They are related questions.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The fees are not exactly hard-coded, the amount per kB is hardcoded. This was enacted after the [block overflow attack](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/421/what-happened-at-block-202612/424#424) where the attacker had to expand the blocksize by flooding it with transactions until they were able to fit more than 512 transactions in a single block, which they were able to do for little cost because tx fees were so cheap at that time. So, the switch to a fixed fee per kB was done to make any kind of flooding or spam attack much more expensive to pull off. I believe the intent is that it is a temporary measure, and it will be removed allowing for dynamic tx fees per kB in the future.

Comment: I hope so. I don't want monero's transaction fees to be like bitcoin's block sizes (which where also supposed to be temporary).

Comment: It can’t be removed entirely, because Sybil attacking the anonymity can ruin it. You probably know by now that the [minimum transaction fee is scaled down as transaction volume increases](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/2531/how-does-the-dynamic-fee-calculation-work).

Answer (score 4):

I doubt most other currencies do not have hardcoded fees.

In any case, some research has started a while back into making fees a function of the past. Variables that could have an influence on fee include block sizes, and transaction volume. Monero price is an external metric, so that seems difficult to integrate into a dynamic calculation, and, if it were to be included, would likely need maintainer input to change it.

A spam attack in 2014 caused the fee to be increased as a first defense. This fee is expected to decrease should the price of monero increase substantially against fiat currency.

Comment: Bitcoin's aren't hard-coded, because they don't have a minimum. You can send a 0-fee transaction. Monero has a minimum because fees are only used for anti-spam, where in Bitcoin they are expected to form the bulk of the mining reward after a certain point in the emission curve.

Comment: You're right, I forgot the fee formula isn't consensus, and I guess most currencies inherit that.

Comment: IOTA is has 0 transaction fees, but it is a DAG and not a blockchain.