# How are fees computed?

Tags: transaction-fees, algorithm

Can someone explain the algorithm to compute Monero transaction fee?

I have seen somewhere it is based transaction size (or something called "weight"?), and some other vague explanation. But I would like to know more deeply how it works.

EDIT:
This is basically the same question as [How does the dynamic fee calculation work?](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/2531/how-does-the-dynamic-fee-calculation-work) but the answer to that question looks out of date. I would like to know how it works in the protocol today.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does the dynamic fee calculation work?](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/2531/how-does-the-dynamic-fee-calculation-work)

Comment: @knaccc - Whilst technically a duplicate, the answer there is outdated. Thus, not sure if it should be marked as duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can someone explain the algorithm to compute Monero transaction fee?

The computation of the current dynamic fee algorithm is explained, in detail, here: https://web.getmonero.org/2017/12/11/A-note-on-fees.html.

> I have seen somewhere it is based transaction size (or something called "weight"?), and some other vague explanation.

"weight" is just another term for size. However, It's not just tx weight that is used in the calculation.

> But I would like to know more deeply how it works.

https://web.getmonero.org/2017/12/11/A-note-on-fees.html

Comment: This was the type explanation I was looking for. That post is old, does it still correspond to the Monero code?

Comment: It's not that old and it's the most recent write-up. Some parameters I think may have been tweaked but it's largely current.

Comment: But seems wrong. Example, this transaction https://xmrchain.net/tx/b87f6fbe15e4ccf408f8995a35b7073ce0d90e06d8335b6a96ee00f0c9ceef73 fee is 0.0000331xmr, size is 1,73kB, median block is 293kB, and block reward is 2.8xmr (says xmrchain.net). But above formula says fee/kB should be (2.8/10)*(300/293)*0.002*(60/300)*4  = 0.000459xmr, so the fee should be 0.0007935xmr. That is almost 25 times more than on xmrchain.net!

Comment: No, the numbers you are using in your calculation are wrong. Re-read the article.

Comment: Can you give a hint what is wrong? Im puzzled.

Comment: NewReward and BaseReward.

Comment: Maybe I am being stupid, sorry about that. As I understand the note, in this case the BaseReward = NewReward because the blocksize is < 300kB, so there is no penalty. And the reward for the block was ~2.8XMR. That is why I have 2.8 as the value for R.

Comment: And by R I am talking about the formula "Fee per kB = (R/R0) * (M0/M) * F0 * (60/300) * 4" ... is this not used when there is no penalty?

Comment: But how are you calculating BaseReward? For that block it should be: BaseReward = 2 * ((S - A) * 2^-20 * 10^-12) where S is 2^64-1 and A is 16979545.930907253176e12

Comment: Yes. And this is 2 * (2^64- 1 - 16979545.930907253176e12) * 2^-20 * 10^-12 = ~2.8?

Comment: The tx you reference has a fee per kb as 0.000019106201. And the block size is 1.8330kb. I don't know what a) the median block size is for the prev 100 blocks to that block or b) what priority level was selected for that tx.

Comment: Hmm, looking at the source code, this article does indeed look a little out of date. Apologies. The source for the base fee per byte can be seen calculated [here](https://github.com/monero-project/monero/blob/f64f59627dddd65a6a99cc057586f6460b5154e1/src/cryptonote_core/blockchain.cpp#L3210)