# What would be the process for creating a Monero transaction on paper?

Tags: transaction-hash

I'm trying to better understand the CryptoNote protocol and Monero's current codebase, and I'm having trouble grasping how transactions are made in the protocol. I've read over the CNS standard and I partially understand topics such as the CryptoNote block template/header, transaction template etc. What I am confused on however, is how all this information is turned into a transaction hash that can be relayed and accepted by the network. I find it that I would have an easier time understanding the whole concept if I were to do it on paper at least partially, so what would be the steps to create a Monero transaction that could be relayed to the network on a piece of paper?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Understanding the structure of a Monero transaction](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/2136/understanding-the-structure-of-a-monero-transaction)

Answer (score 1):

This is the structure of a Monero transaction, listed in the exact order that the information will appear in the transaction structure: [Size requirements for different "pieces" of a Monero transaction](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/5664/size-requirements-for-different-pieces-of-a-monero-transaction/5665#5665)

Many of these terms will be confusing to you. A great resource for understanding all of the elements of a Monero transaction is the Zero to Monero paper https://ww.getmonero.org/library/Zero-to-Monero-1-0-0.pdf