# What is the max no of input for Monero tx? How does it affect the no of decoys?

Tags: transaction-data

Assume the ring size = 11.

If I have 1 input, 10 decoys are added. 1 key image.

If I have N input, 11 - N decoys are added. N key image.

Is the above statement true?

Does it mean that if the number of inputs increases, there is less privacy?

Answer (score 2):

> What is the max no of input for Monero tx?

The only restriction affecting the quantity of inputs a tx can include is the overall tx size maximum, 149.4kB [[src]](https://github.com/monero-project/monero/blob/0f233c6ad83eaa7abe2469c657eda374d19ab089/src/cryptonote_core/tx_pool.cpp#L112).

> How does it affect the no of decoys?

Each input has its own ring. Thus for *each* input being spent there is the input itself, 10 decoys and 1 key image.

> Does it mean that if the number of inputs increases, there is less privacy?

No. See previous point.

Comment: i check the xmr block explorer. Is it 1 input is approx 830 bytes, 1 output is 472 bytes?

Comment: I believe `CRYPTONOTE_MAX_TX_SIZE` can never be reached, since `get_transaction_weight_limit()` will always return 149.4kB.

Comment: @koe good spot. I'll update.

Comment: @CiscoMmu very roughly speaking, yes, each additional input adds ~800 bytes. Outputs, much less. See this [answer](https://monero.stackexchange.com/a/5665/7493).