# What is the block header's minor_version for?

Tags: blockchain

Minor version is one of the 5 fields in Monero block headers.

The answer here [What is the format of a block in the Monero Blockchain?](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/3958/what-is-the-format-of-a-block-in-the-monero-blockchain/6461#6461) says

"uint8_t minor_version;  // now used as a voting mechanism, rather than how this particular block is built"

This is vague, can someone please clarify and elaborate?

Answer (score 3):

It's used to mark which consensus version the mining node supports. It used to be there was a voting mechanism so that consensus changes would happen when enough nodes would claim the new version, but that was not working well, and deemed too complex, so it's now just indicative.

Comment: Is the consensus version different from the major_version, which indicates the hard fork number? What is the difference between consensus versions?

Comment: No, it's the same. I won't list all the differences between consensus versions.

Comment: So the minor version indicates which major version a mining node cares about, even if it's different from the version their actual blocks conform to? Is this meaningful?