# Are 0-output transactions possible?

Tags: transaction-data, transaction-fees

Is it possible (as in allowed by consensus, not doable with today's software) to create a zero-output transaction in Monero? In other words, is it possible to create a transaction whose inputs are entirely used as fees and creates no new outputs?

Answer (score 7):

Yes, it is possible, and while I can't point at it right now, I know there's at least one in the chain.

Comment: Interesting. I'd assume that due to the use of commitment blinding factors, there has to be at least one output unless the only inputs referenced in the transaction were originally created in a coinbase transaction and thus do not have blinding factors associated with them? Would love to see the transaction you're referring to on the blockchain.

Comment: Well, the transaction I'm thinking of was pre-rct. I don't think it's forbidden post-rct either, but I'm not 100% sure about it.

Comment: Hmm... okay, thanks for the discussion fam. I guess I'll leave the question open until we can get a more precise answer post-rct.

Answer (score 1):

There are exactly `534` transactions with `0` output (block [1,1500000]), `511` of them being in the [famous block 202612](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/421/what-happened-at-block-202612)

Example:

- [f55800d539059de53b57385a5e11efcff3da27b61e2eff1e1ba712d5eeb1d783](https://moneroblocks.info/search/f55800d539059de53b57385a5e11efcff3da27b61e2eff1e1ba712d5eeb1d783)
- [f6b1637c4d4c95db5f16a872dc678849346ca7324aef2711406fff25ad213108](https://moneroblocks.info/search/f6b1637c4d4c95db5f16a872dc678849346ca7324aef2711406fff25ad213108)